# Why Object removes the duplicate elements from an array of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am solving a task and faced this issue while I was trying to convert an array of integers into an object. The object will carry the array's elements as keys and its indices as value, I tried something like this:

```js
let array = [2, 2, 4, 3]
let dic = {};

//Method # 1
array.forEach((item, index) => dic[item] = index)

//Method # 2
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    dic[array[i]] = i;
}

//Method # 3
dic = new Map()
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    dic.set(arra[i] ,i);
}
```

All of them gave me the same results, i.e. `2` in the array is duplicated, and it removes it. That's what I don't want.

Comment: Don't use `number` values as object property keys unless you know exactly what you're doing (JavaScript _does_ allow this, but it's a can of worms). Is there a reason you can't do something simpler, like using a `Map` object instead?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in an object

Comment: My question is, why do you want to turn that array into an object in the first place?

Comment: @all I have a situation, where I am requried to convert the array to object, I will try to find a simpler way, I can do something like Object.assign({}, array) as well.

Comment: *Why* though? Why do you need an object instead? An array is ideal to store a bunch of numbers in order, which goal is supposed to be accomplished by turning this into an Object?

Comment: @ChrisG, you might be aware of Hash Maps, I am solving some algorithms and I am trying to solve a problem in O(n) and not O(n^2)

Comment: I'm aware of HashMaps. What's the specific algorithm/problem?

Comment: @ChrisG https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ice-cream-parlor/problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use duplicate keys. Why are you using the values as the keys instead of the indices? If you use the indices as the key and keep the value it will work:

```
array.forEach((item, index) => dic[index] = item)
```

Comment: Upvoting this because it's the first step to solving the challenge successfully.

Answer (score 2):

What is done in all of your solutions with an example of the first method:

```
//Method # 1
array.forEach((item, index) => dic[item] = index)
```

will lead to:

```
dic[2] = 0
dic[2] = 1 // will overwrite the previous value
dic[3] = 2
dic[4] = 3
```

As you can see no element is removed but `dic[2]` will be overwritten.

If you want to map an array with non-unique values to a hashmap then instead of scalar values you can just add the elements to an array like that:

The Hashmap's TypeScript would look like that:

```
type MyMap = Record<number, number[]>
```

The code:

```
const map = array.reduce((result, current, index) => ({
  ...result,
  [current]: [...(result[index] || []), index]
}), {});
```

[array.reduce reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: This is true but doesn't really solve OP's problem :/

Comment: This is only possible in your case if you store the index in an array instead of a scalar value in your map. Added the solution